# Extracting multiple agencies from a GTFS file

Tags: gtfs

I can use the [transitland-lib](https://github.com/interline-io/transitland-lib) to extract a single agency from a GTFS file and create a new one [like this](https://medium.com/@fbaierl1/how-to-extract-a-single-agency-from-a-gtfs-file-and-use-that-to-run-otp-with-docker-cdecee68879a):

```
sudo ./transitland-linux extract -extract-agency 53 germany.gtfs.zip my_agency.gtfs.zip
```

Is there a convenient way of extracting multiple agencies in a similar fashion? So e.g. can I somehow use the extract command somewhat like this:

```
sudo ./transitland-linux extract -extract-agency 53,54 germany.gtfs.zip my_agency.gtfs.zip
```

.. to create a new GTFS file that contains only agency 53 and 54?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extract multiple agencies by chaining multiple arguments, like so:

```bash
sudo ./transitland-linux extract -extract-agency 53 -extract-agency 54 germany.gtfs.zip my_agency.gtfs.zip
```

---

P.S. Glad you are making good use of transitland-lib!

Comment: Great, that may be a simpler solution than my use of onebusaway. Thanks for the great input. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the [onebusaway-gtfs-transformer-cli command-line application](http://developer.onebusaway.org/modules/onebusaway-gtfs-modules/1.3.4-SNAPSHOT/onebusaway-gtfs-transformer-cli.html).

Specifically "retain an entity":

```
{"op":"retain", "match":{"file":"agency.txt", "agency_id":"53"}}
{"op":"retain", "match":{"file":"agency.txt", "agency_id":"54"}}
```